# Command line tool for connecting to wireless (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, command-line

I was wondering how to connect to wireless in a Linux command line environment -> I'm looking for a ncurses like program to do this, not a bunch of commands and files to edit. Is there one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [wicd](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1505136) rather than network manager to control your network interfaces. It has an ncurses GUI available.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to connect to a wireless network? There's a standard tool for this on Ubuntu, the Network Manager. See e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/internet/C/wireless-connecting.html for details.

If you cannot use X (which Network Manager needs), you should also be able to set up networking manually, the way Debian does it. Debian offers several mechanisms to do this. The easiest is to just put a block for your interface into `/etc/network/interfaces`. Sample block for a WLAN network interface:

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid MyNetWork
        # plaintext passphrase
        wpa-psk plaintextsecret
```

Using the config above, you can then type (as root)

```
ifup wlan0
```

to activate the interface (`ifdown wlan0` to deactivate).

See http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi for more information.

Comment: Just to clarify -- NM does not need X. `nm-applet` needs X. You can easily run NM with just the daemon and it will connect to any system connections it has defined. There are also a few CLI tools for interacting with NM

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is correct (though it may not be the best way to go).